# Laravel 5: Use 301 instead of 302

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

How can I update my Laravel app to use the `301` error code when redirecting instead of the default `302` that Laravel is currently using?

For example, in my `routes.php` I use the `redirect()` function to set the error code `301`:

`return redirect('URL_GOES_HERE/', 301);`

But I have many redirects happening in the app. Is there a way to simply change the default `302` to be `301` across all redirects?

Comment: You don't want to use custom error views  ?

Comment: @NinoArmani No, I need to redirect with 301 error code to other URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Redirector defining 302 as a default value
here it is a full reference about [Redirector.php](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html)
you can override it

Answer (score -1):

Here you check error response code
**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
  // If response code 404 then do this
  if($e->getStatusCode() == 404)
  {  
    return redirect()->to('/error'); 
  }

  // If response code 301
  if($e->getStatusCode() == 301)
  {  
    return redirect()->to('/do'); 
  }

  if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
    $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
  }

  if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Please login again.');
  }

  return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: But doesn't `$e->getStatusCode() == 301` checks if the response code is `301`? Mine is by default `302`. What I need to do is to change the default `302` to be `301`. Each URL that must be redirected using `301` has its own URL where it should be redirected.